# VB.NET Change text in new form from sender

Tags: vb.net, label

I am trying to open a loading screen, and then update the status bar on the loading screen with the status of the application. I have the following.

LoadingProgressScreen.vb:

```
Friend WithEvents StatusText As Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel
Public Sub newStatus(NewStatusText As String)
    Me.StatusText.Text = NewStatusText
End Sub
```

Main.vb:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim dateRequest As New DateRequest
  Application.Run(dateRequest)

  dateStr = dateRequest.DeliveryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
  DataUploader(dateStr)
End Sub

Sub DataUploader(ByVal dateStr As String)
  Dim loadingScreen As New LoadingProgressScreen
  Application.Run(loadingScreen)
  loadingScreen.newStatus("Gathering data for " & dateStr)
  conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=" & databaseDSN & ";Uid=" & databaseUsername & ";Pwd=" & databasePassword
  ...
  conn.Open()
  ...
  Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
  ...
End Sub
```

The DateRequest Form is simply a calendar to select a date.

I do not receive the desired outcome.

I see other questions where people are changing text on the initial form from the new one created, but I can not find anything that helps in this situation.

Comment: Are you talking about a splash screen? If so, that functionality is built into VS so you should use that. The gotcha is that the splash screen form is created on a secondary thread, so you have to marshal a call to that thread to update it.

Comment: Why do you have `Application.Run()` there? How do you plan to use `loadingScreen`? What is the relation with `Main`? Just setting a control's text?

Comment: If I use `loadingScreen.Show()` it freezes / does not load properly

Comment: The application allows users to select a date from the main screen and then the database gathers data for that date and uploads it to a third party api. This is not a splash screen as the app is already running, this just so the user sees something while it is parsing the data

Comment: `loadingScreen.Show()` freezes? Sorry, but you need to give a lot more context to this question. In a common STAThread, `Application.Run()` won't work, while `Show()` won't freeze anything (unless you're doing sync work in the UI Thread, that is, then that's the wrong part. Do that work in a Task or Backgroundworker).

Comment: You might benefit from [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567).

Comment: @Jimi I have updated my code snippet some more. Sorry for the lack of context originally. I am trying to do some database stuff, and yes, `Show()` freezes- currently. Maybe I should do that as a task or backgroundworker though?

Comment: Well, yes. @jmcilhinney just pointed you to a BackgroundWorker sample. It's probably easier to implement if you haven't used the async/await pattern yet, or you're unfamiliar with the TPL in general.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that instead of modifying the existing code base someone else wrote, I am just going to rewrite this application. It is not very big, and this way I can optimize it better. Thanks!